# SSH hangs when installing ohmyzsh remotely

Tags: ssh, shell

I'm trying to install Oh my zsh through script:

```
ssh username@host "
   sh -c \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)\"
"
```

However, when the install finishes, it hangs, the command doesn't exit. It waits for my input and I have to pres CTRL+C so it ends. How can I make it run and exit itself?

I found some answers here with similar issues so I tried executing these but the result was pretty much the same.

```
sh -c \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)\" &
sh -c \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)\" 1>&2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing the script itself, I guess it is not really possible without a small modification at the end of it.

The line `env zsh -l` actually runs zsh, and it is this zsh which waits for your input. I would suggest forking this script and removing this line.

The cause why `&` didn't work is because the ssh session wasn't closed because of a background task not finishing (the actual `env zsh -l` line).

You can also try to run the script with nohup, which will disconnect the script from the actual ssh session.

`nohup sh -c \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)\" &`

But this way it would be still spawning zsh at the end, leaving it with an unused process disconnected from anything.

UPDATE:

Another way to cope with the problem may be using `sed` to strip out the unneeded command. The resulting command would be like this:

```
sh -c \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh | sed '/env zsh -l/d')\"
```

Comment: [The install script](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/tools/install.sh) has been updated to use `exec` instead of `env`, so the `sed` component would now need to be `| sed '/exec zsh -l/d'`, however there is now [an option](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/tools/install.sh#L315-L318) to natively skip running zsh by setting the environment var `RUNZSH` to `no`, i.e. `RUNZSH=no sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`